# R : How can I remove singletons within tidyverse groups across all columns of my dataframe?

Tags: r, group-by, conditional-statements, dplyr

I am working on a large dataset of ASV detections where each sample name has three replications from different PCR runs. My goal is to remove singletons from the dataset. This means that if a sample name has only one ASV detection in all three replication, I want that 1 to be turned into a zero.

So far I have been able to do this on a small scale with 3 ASVs, but my method requires that I write out each ASV name. This won't work for me as my dataset has 9000 ASVs. I need a better method to remove the singletons.

This is what I have done so far:

```
#make dataframe
sample.name <- c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c")
data <- as.data.frame(sample.name)
data$sample.pcr <- c("1","2","3","1","2","3","1","2","3")
data$AVS1 <- c(3,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1)
data$AVS2 <- c(0,1,0,2,3,0,1,0,0)
data$AVS3 <- c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,5,0)

#mutate so that if the sum of a sample.name group is 1 for an ASV then make that sum 0
data %>%
  group_by(sample.name) %>%
  mutate(AVS1 = case_when(sum(AVS1)==1 ~ 0,
                          T ~ AVS1),
         AVS2 = case_when(sum(AVS2)==1 ~ 0,
                          T ~ AVS2),
         AVS2 = case_when(sum(AVS3)==1 ~ 0,
                          T ~ AVS3))
```

UPDATE:

This is the solution provided by @akrun.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
   group_by(sample.name) %>%
   mutate(across(starts_with('AVS'), ~ case_when(sum(.) == 1 ~ 0, TRUE ~ .)))
```

They suggested a modification of `case_when` to `~ case_when(sum(.) == 1 ~ 0L, TRUE ~ .)))`.
With the modification and by changing "AVS" -> "ASV" in `starts_with()` I was able to remove the singletons from my dataset.

This is the method I used to test if there are singletons in my dataset:

```
# look and see if there are singletons
#we do this by summing occurrences of ASV in PCR reps per sample
#if there is a singleton, the sum of occurrences for an ASV in a sample will be equal to one
t <- data%>% group_by(sample.name) %>% #make group
  select(-sample.pcr) %>% #remove column
  dplyr::summarise(across(.fns=sum)) # sum an ASV's occurrence for a sample, do this across the whole dataset
sum(t==1) #check how many sums were equal to one - if this is greater than 0 then we need to remove singletons
```

Comment: Do you want to `sum` `AVS` values or count the unique values in it by group?

Comment: My goal is to find if in a group of 3 pcr reps if there are any single occurrences of  an ASV. For example, if sample a for ASV1 has occurrences as follows : pcr1- 1, pcr2-0, pcr3-0. In this case I would want to have pcr1, which is a single occurrence of an ASV in a sample, removed so that sample a for ASV1 would have pcr1-0, pcr2-0, pcr3-0. I used ``sum``` as a way to test for this case so that a 1 could be replaced with a zero. @RonakShah is there a way to look specifically for unique 1s in a group of zeros?

Answer (score 0):

We could use `across` to apply the function on multiple columns

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
   group_by(sample.name) %>%
   mutate(across(starts_with('AVS'), ~ case_when(sum(.) == 1 ~ 0, TRUE ~ .)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works perfectly with my example data, but for some reason is not working with my real data. Could this be because in my example data the ASV columns have num values but in my real data the ASV column values are int? But when I mutated across with as.numeric so that all values in the ASV columns were dbl it wasn't working for me either. Any suggestions on what I should do?

Comment: @a.m It would work for both `num` and `int`.  Can you check if any of the ASV columns are non-numeric i.e. character i.e. check `str(data[grep("^AVS", names(data))])`

Comment: or `all(sapply(data[grep("^AVS", names(data))], is.numeric))`

Comment: when I do ```all(sapply(str(select(dataCo1.run2,contains("ASV"))), is.numeric))```   I am told ```TRUE``` and all listed columns are ```int```. Do you have any ideas about what I should try next?

Comment: @a.m then my code should have worked.  Can you try `~ case_when(sum(.) == 1 ~ 0L, TRUE ~ .)))`

Comment: thank you for getting back to me and for all your help with this. ```~ case_when(sum(.) == 1 ~ 0L, TRUE ~ .)))``` didn't work for my real data set and it was giving me errors for my dummy dataset. I'm wondering if I should be using a different method for testing if it worked? Right now I am using ```t <- data%>% group_by(sample.name) %>% select(-sample.pcr) %>%  dplyr::summarise(across(.fns=sum))``` and ```sum(t==1) ``` This test works for my dummy data, but since my real data is acting differently I wonder if I should be using a different test? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @a.m Do you have NA elements in the dataset?  In that case use `sum(., na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: I just checked and I have no NA elements in the dataset.

Comment: @a.m If you can update your post with a small example that shows the error, I can test it ie, preferably with `dput`